# After Xcode 7.2 beta, project not working on 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After using Xcode 7.2 beta, I turned back to my project in Xcode 7.1, and the app crashes on startup, I get this:
[image: Error]

If i comment this line, I get a random error somewhere else. The app was working perfectly, I am sorry there isn't much to explain, but I really dont know whats causing this error.
 I tried deleting Derived data and still the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have any breakpoints set?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a breakpoint causing you some troubles.
Type "br del" in the console (lldb), type "Y" and enter to delete all breakpoints.

Comment: Could it be something do with certificates or provision files? Because I recently revoked them and signed them from all over again?

Comment: I don't think so... a certificates or provisioning profiles problem should come up at compilation time since it's when your app is being signed.

Comment: Are you using a simulator or a device? Try to delete your app and relaunch. When I have this kind of problems I always try to have the workspace as clean as possible. (clean derived data, check if something change in the CVS,...)